# How to setup a connection string to access the asp.net web application from a different system?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This is my connection string:

```html
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Database" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="ASPNETDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I am trying to access my application from a different system I am getting the following error, how ever it run perfectly from my system.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details. )

How to configure the setting of this connection string so that the web application can run smoothly without creating a new connection string on the different system?

Note: I am using a localdb from App_Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be since it's not a full blown SQL Server installation instance rather you are using `Local DB` as can be seen in your post `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0`.

You will have to have SQL Server installation and then use that Db server IP/Hostname in connection string rather `LocalDB`.

See here for more information: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

Comment: Hi Rahul, so would installing the full version of sql server fix this? please help

Comment: @KartheekNagulapati, Yes it will. Install SQLServer and then use that machine IP/Hostname. Follow MSDN for more information.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I am doing a mini project and was instructed to use app_data to store the application data using .mdf file which I created using visual studio. Is there any other way to fix this?